# Different template for second page of posts Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to have a different template for the second page of posts, here's the code I came up with.

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) { ?>
SOME HTML
<?php } else if (is_page('chi-sono')){ ?>
SOME HTML
<?php } else if (is_paged()){} else{}?>
```

It seems straightforward to me but the elseif is_paged() doesn't work, what am I doing wrong? I also tried

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged'));
elseif ($paged >= 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_home()` return `true` on blog page so you are not going on `is_paged()`.

try this

```
if (is_home()) {
    if (is_paged()) {
        echo 'second page';
    } else {
        echo 'home page';
    }
}
```